# SQL Server - Query to join two tables based on columnName field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing SQL Server table structure like the following:

```
--Entries Table--
*Company* | *MusicProduct* | *FoodProduct* | *PCProduct* | *PhoneProduct* |
  Apple         iPod             null           iMac           iPhone
  Dell          null             null          Dellbook         null
```

The Primary Key on the above table is `Company`

```
--Questions Table--
*ColumnName*    |   Questions
 MusicProduct        What mp3 device the company known for?
 FoodProduct         What food product describes the company best?
 PCProduct           What PC?
 PhoneProduct        What phone does the company give employees?
```

The Primary Key on the above table is `ColumnName` and it contains a row for each of the non-key columns in the first table. This certainly feels like bad design, but it preexists my work.

I basically want a query that will return rows with a question and answer, ignoring questions with null answers, for a chosen single company. The output for Apple would look like this (three rows):

```
  Question                                        Answer
  What mp3 device the company known for?          iPod
  What PC?                                        iMac
  What phone does the company give employees?     iPhone
```

How can I best accomplish this with the above? Would some sort of new reference table be the way to go?

Comment: First thing I would do is learn to design relational tables. This struture is wholly unacceptable as a database design. YOu have more than one answer for many of these questions you ant, you need child tables.

Comment: If one of the proposed solutions answered your question, you should mark it as the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside it. This benefits other users coming across your question e. g. via Google. Actually, I do not care if you mark my answer or @sqlhdv's as the correct one, I just want to explain how StackOverflow is meant to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
select q.question, product as answer
from
(select company, Musicproduct, Foodproduct, PCProduct, phoneproduct from Entries ) p
unpivot ( product for Products in (Musicproduct, Foodproduct, PCProduct, phoneproduct)
) unpvt
join questions q on unpvt.product = q.answer;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have a fix number of columns in your entries table, you can use a `CASE` expression to map from the ColumnName column in the Questions table to the column to return:

```
WITH a as(
     SELECT q.Question
          ,CASE q.ColumnName
                WHEN 'MusicProduct' THEN e.MusicProduct
                WHEN 'FoodProduct' THEN e.FoodProduct
                WHEN 'PCProduct' THEN e.PCProduct
                WHEN 'PhoneProduct' THEN e.PhoneProduct
           END as Answer
      FROM Questions q
           CROSS JOIN Entries
     WHERE q.Company = 'Apple'
   )
 SELECT Question, Answer
   FROM a
  WHERE Answer IS NOT NULL
```

Using a CTE allows you to use `Answer` in the `WHERE` condition, avoiding to have to repeat the long `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause, which could cause errors in case you need to change anything in it.